# How do I select an item from a list in a function in python?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to create a menu item using functions with lists and sets as well as `if` and `elif` statements.  I'm also trying to create these functions in separate modules of their own and then import them into the main module.

In the code below I've created the function and now I want to start with the `if` and `elif` statements linked to an `input` statement.

When I run the code and select the first option the CMD pops up and says "press any button to continue" without showing the desired input.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def Main_Menu():
    MainMenuItems = ['1. Bacon & Eggs-$2.00', '2. Full-Course Meal-$3.99', '3. Oatmeal-$1.00', '4. Hamburger & Fries-$3.00']
    print(*MainMenuItems, sep='\n')

    choice = int(input("Please select a menu item from the list above: "))

    if choice is [0]:
        print("You chose ", MainMenuItems[1])
```

Comment: `if choice is [0]:` definitely won't work.You're comparing object identtity to a list containing `0`. You need `==`, not `is`, to test for equality. But I'm not sure what you're trying to compare with; the first index of `MainMenuItems`?

Comment: `choice` will never be the object `[0]`, which is what you are asking Python to test. You don't want to use `is` here, you want to use `==`, and test against a single integer value: `if choice == 0:`.

Comment: You could debug this problem by adding a `else` block so that you could see what is the flow of your program

Comment: Your menu doesn't include the option `0` however. If you were hoping to parse the `MainMenuItems` list, then you'd have to use string processing to find the numbers that the text uses, so `options = [int(item.partition('.')[0] for item in MainMenuItems]` and then `if choice in options: print("You chose", MainMenuItems[options.index(choice)]`.

Comment: @Aryerez: no, it doesn't need to do that. The `print()` function call is excellent and correct.

Comment: The other option is that you always number your menu items starting at 1, and then you can use `choice - 1` as an index into the list. If the user entered `1`, then `choice - 1` is 0 and so `MainMenuItems[0]` is the first string entry in the menu, the one that starts with `1.`.

Answer (score 0):

You should test `if choice == 0:` instead of `if choice is [0]:`.

Note that you could directly call

```py
print("You chose ", MainMenuItems[choice - 1])
```

to print the chosen item, without if statement.

Comment: But there is no option `0` in the menu text.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I've tried the suggestions above as well as your answer and the one below, it hasn't changed the outcome. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need an if to do so. And you have to know that list indexes begin with 0, so when you chose number 1, your refer to the 0 index item:

Yo can do it with just a print:

```
print("You chose ", MainMenuItems[choice-1])
```